# How can I search with Unicode characters in elasticsearch?

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch, unicode

I have indexed MySQL column into elasticsearch and this column have some AR/EN/RO languages values.
How can I search within these indexes with a unicode string ?

```
$hosts = ['localhost:9200'];              
$client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();  

$body = '{  "query": {
"filtered": {
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"query": {"wildcard": {"text": {"value": "*'.$term.'*"}}}},
        {"query": {"wildcard": {"group": {"value": "hotels_cities"}}}}
      ]
    }
  }
}  }}';



$params['index'] = 'my_custom_index_name';
$params['type']  = 'translator_translations';
$params['body'] = $body;

$results = $client->search($params);
```

The out put hits is zero.

-There is something called analyzer but there is no information about how to use it in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer of how to index unicode languages characters in Elasticsearch, hope this would be useful to any one.

- First you have to **set your index name**
- Second **Set your new language settings with filter and language analyzer**, Like this:

  ```
  $client = ClientBuilder::create()       // Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
              ->setHosts(['localhost:9200'])      // Set the hosts
              ->build();

  $lang = 'el'; // Greek in my case

  $param['index'] = 'test_' . $lang; // index name

  // uncomment this line if you want to delete an existing index
  // $response = $client->indices()->delete($param);

  $body = '{
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "greek_stop": {
            "type":       "stop",
            "stopwords":  "_greek_" 
          },
          "greek_lowercase": {
            "type":       "lowercase",
            "language":   "greek"
          },
          "greek_keywords": {
            "type":       "keyword_marker",
            "keywords":   ["παράδειγμα"] 
          },
          "greek_stemmer": {
            "type":       "stemmer",
            "language":   "greek"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "greek": {
            "tokenizer":  "standard",
            "filter": [
              "greek_lowercase",
              "greek_stop",
              "greek_keywords",
              "greek_stemmer"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }';

  $param['body'] = $body; // store the JSON body as a parameter in the main array

  $response = $client->indices()->create($param);
  ```

Then start indexing your values with Greek characters

Answer (score 0):

you should use fieldname.keyword

```
$rowArray = array();
$rowArray['term'] = array();
$rowArray['term']['title.keyword'] = (string)$csvRow[1];
$whereArray['bool']['must'][] = $rowArray;
```